# Running a speculative transaction in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, locking, transaction

I have a long-running transaction that I know is always going to be rolled back.

Is there a way to run this transaction so that it doesn't acquire any locks in the database? The transaction inserts and updates rows, but these changes will never persist in the database and in general should not be visible to anybody outside the transaction.

Here is a more specific example.

Connection 1:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE foobar SET something = 1;
COMMIT
```

Connection 2:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE foobar SET something = 2;
ROLLBACK
```

I want to prevent connection 2 from blocking connection 1. I can add SQL statements in the transaction, but I cannot easily change the queries.

Comment: This seems like a really odd use case, I'm curious as to why you need to do this in the first place. Something tells me the true solution may have nothing to do with transactions and more with how/why you're trying to achieve X

Comment: **Technically**, the only way to **not** have locking is to use In Memory objects. Now, if your question is about removing all locking - that's the answer. If the question is How do I reduce the impact of my speculative queries, that's a different answer. Please let us know which you're looking for.

Comment: @SeanGallardy brings up a good point. I'd also think of trying to use temp tables, but that is completely dependent on your workload, table sizes, etc. etc.

Comment: @LowlyDBA This application has a rather complicated algorithm that has parts of its logic written in stored procedures and rest of the code assumes that the objects are present in the database. Ideally, this logic would not be intermingled with database access logic... but refactoring the code for this purpose is not feasible at this point.

Comment: @hrnt I have seen systems that do what you describe and this often has unintended consequences. Enabling RCSI for the database *may* help, but even then I've seen cases where the logic wasn't written properly and the rollback wasn't always performed. You are much better off doing the "not feasible" part - find a way to do this validation of the algorithm *without* the speculative/rolled back transaction. Continuing this way will eventually burn you.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a built-in way to run a "speculative transaction" in SQL Server.

If multiple transactions make incompatible changes, there will be blocking. You would need separate copies of the data to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can run this without acquiring any locks, per se, but you *may be able to reduce locks this transaction acquires* by utilizing an [optimistic locking](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) isolation level such as either `SNAPSHOT` or `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` [isolation levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql).  This may have adverse affects on your database in general, so I wouldn't recommend enabling either of these options without proper testing.... and frankly, if you're going to be testing this, you may as well test your long-running transaction somewhere other than Production as well.

Comment: optimistic locking guarantees that readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers. It is mentioned in question that transaction do insert and updates, so optimistic locking will not help.

Comment: @ArtashesKhachatryan `reduce locks` being the operative words in my answer as there is likely more occurring than just that in a long-running transaction, but fair enough...

Comment: Unfortunately SNAPSHOT isolation level locks records it updates so it doesn't help in this case :(

Comment: @hmt there's `SNAPSHOT` and there's `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`. They are not the same. From MSDN, about the 2nd: *"If READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is set to ON, the Database Engine uses row versioning to present each statement with a transactionally consistent snapshot of the data as it existed at the start of the statement. Locks are not used to protect the data from updates by other transactions."*

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I know, we have been running with READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT for a long time already. Writers block other writers with RCSI (just like with SNAPSHOT isolation). See e.g. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/read-committed-snapshot-isolation-writers-block-rcsi/